# Calculating average from urllib response using python

Tags: python, api, urllib

I want to constantly **calculate the speed of vehicles during 5 min and calculate the average**, if the average speed is more than 80 send an email...

so far i can get the speed per vehicle once and send email,the issue is continuously getting it and calculating the average(5 speeds(each per min) per vehicle)
I have attached the code, dont mind the indentation i have no errors.

```
def check_speed():
    try:
        response = urlopen(full_url)
        outp = response.read()
        print outp
        response2 = urlopen(g_url)
        pasa = json.loads(outp)
        for i in pasa:
            print i['objectno']
            print i['objectname']
            print i['longitude']
            print i['latitude']
            print i['odometer']
            stand=i['standstill']
            print stand


            if stand==0:
                print 'Vehicle Moving'
                if 'speed' in i:

                    print i['speed']
                    veh = i['objectname']

                    speed = i['speed']
                    if int(speed)>=86:
                        speed1=int(speed)


                    #send email
                        print 'over speed'
                        msg = MIMEMultipart()
                        ccaddr = "addr1@gmail.com"
                        toaddr = "addr2@gmail.com"
                        fromaddr = "from@gmail.com"
                        bccadr = "addr3@gmail.com"
                        rcpt = ccaddr.split(",") + bccadr.split(",") + [toaddr]
                        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

                        msg['Subject'] = 'Signaling Overspeed '
                        msg['From'] = fromaddr
                        msg['To'] = toaddr
                        msg['CC'] = ccaddr
                        msg['Bcc'] = bccadr

                        if 'drivername' in i:
                            driver = i['drivername']
                            body = "Vehicle "+veh+" Driven by "+driver+" is moving on "+str(speed)
                        else:
                            body = "Vehicle " + veh +" is moving on " + str(speed)
                        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
                        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                        server.starttls()
                        server.login(fromaddr, "pwd")
                        text = msg.as_string()
                        server.sendmail(fromaddr, rcpt, text)
                        server.quit()

                    elif speed==i['speed']<50:
                        print 'traffic jam'

            elif stand==1:

                print 'Vehicle not Moving'





    except URLError, e:
        print 'Got an error code:', e
    time.sleep(300)

#loop that get the speed of vehicles
while True:
    check_speed()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to store the time that the last value was calculated and what that value was. For doing this, you can either:

- Use a database (probably not needed in the above, since this is pretty straightforward).
- Use a class with perhaps the time/speed stored as a tuple where you can keep everything in memory, such as `[(time1, speed1), (time2, speed2), ...]`.
- Finally, you could return a `time, speed` tuple in your `check_speed()` function and store it in a list in the while loop. For example:

.

```
my_values = []
while True:
    time, speed = check_speed()
    my_values.append((time, speed))
```

With the above structure it would be easy to calculate averages over the last minute, hour, day, etc.

Comment: thank you, I thought of a database too but it seems useless to keep those info after the email is sent, can you give me an example of code showing how that class would be?, Actually the time isnt that needed it is saving in var1,var2,var3,var4,var5 calculate mean then if above it is 80 send email